# .net web api data file placement issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a .net4 web api that I published to azure site, in my development environment, I have a file (data.csv) that I reference to for small checking type of action, I put it under `C:\Program File\IIS Express` folder and it works. So where should I put this file on the azure web site?

I see there are the following folders on the web server:

```
/site
   deployments/
   locks/
   wwwroot/
     bin/
     Content/
     Scripts/
     Views/
```

I tried a few places, but no success, so where should I place this data.csv file?

Answer (score 0):

In content and reference it as "~/Content"

What you are probably doing is using Directory to get current directory which takes the path where the application is running. If you didn't use IIS it would probably be in bin/Debug/etc